# Tab sends to end of document in Document Viewer

Tags: 15.10, pdf, evince

I am reading some pdf documents in Document Viewer in Ubuntu 15.10 and want to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch between windows.  If I accidentally press just <kbd>Tab</kbd> in Document Viewer's window, it scrolls all the way down till the end of the document and I can't even stop it from scrolling.

Every time this happens I have to scroll back and find the initial position of the document and it is very annoying.

Is there a way to stop it scrolling on pressing the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue, quite annoying.

It seems to be a focus bug in evince: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=784219#5. It's fixed in versions 3.17.3+ (and back-ported to 3.14.2) however Ubuntu 15.10 is using 3.16.1. Not so sure how easy it is to upgrade/downgrade evince to these versions.

**Edit:** I back-ported the patch to 3.16.1 (the changes are minor) and the issue is gone. You can download my packages (if you trust me enough, otherwise it's pretty easy to build it yourself) here: https://cloud.bwns.be/index.php/s/06ssbVK3zNJwhVG (you don't need to install all the packages, I think evince and evince-common are enough).

Comment: Could you tell me how to go about backporting? I seem to be stuck with the same issue

Comment: I fetched the source packages/dependencies with apt-get, compares the patch in the above link with the source in 3.16.1 and modified what changed. Then I just build it and installed the package. (google "apt-get debian rebuild package" or similar for more details).